# sum up multiple rows by condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, sum, rows

I know there are a lot of similar questions on how to sum up a column under a condition in R. But I somehow cannot implement the function `aggregate` or `dplyr::group_by(df) %>%  summarise(variable = sum(variable))` in my data. Also [Combine rows and sum their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535261/combine-rows-and-sum-their-values) does not help me. But maybe you can?
I want to merge and sum up rows of a data.frame in R.

```
df <- data.frame(file=c('sample1','sample1','sample2','sample3','sample2'),gene1=c(34,365,76,0,4),gene2=c(34,0,0,456,0))
> df
     file gene1 gene2
1 sample1    34    34
2 sample1   365     0
3 sample2    76     0
4 sample3     0   456
5 sample2    4      0
```

The output should look like this

```
 file gene1 gene2
1 sample1    399    34
2 sample2    80     0
3 sample3     0   456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *base* you can use `rowsum` to *sum up rows by group*.

```
rowsum(df[-1], df[,1])
#        gene1 gene2
#sample1   399    34
#sample2    80     0
#sample3     0   456
```

Or using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(.~file, df, sum)
#     file gene1 gene2
#1 sample1   399    34
#2 sample2    80     0
#3 sample3     0   456
```

Or using `by`:

```
do.call(rbind, by(df[-1], df[,1], colSums))
#        gene1 gene2
#sample1   399    34
#sample2    80     0
#sample3     0   456
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` approach would be:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(file) %>% summarise_all(.funs = sum,na.rm=T)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  file    gene1 gene2
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 sample1   399    34
2 sample2    80     0
3 sample3     0   456
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(file) %>% 
  summarise(gene1 = sum(gene1), gene2 = sum(gene2))
```

or `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[,.(gene1 = sum(gene1), gene2 = sum(gene2)), by= .(file)]
      file gene1 gene2
1: sample1   399    34
2: sample2    80     0
3: sample3     0   456
```